# Parse JSON payload in Spring MVC

Tags: json, spring-rest

I started studied web service recently with Spring and I would like to know how to parse String into JSON. My web service allow the Motus game so a player have to find a word and has 5 attempts to do it.

I would like to post the word chose by the users into the request body of the HTTP request.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/jouer")
public void plays(@RequestBody String name){
   users.plays(name);
}
```

The JSON in the body would be like this:

```
{
  "name": "elephant"
}
```

I wouldn't like to create classes to map the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

> I wouldn't like to create classes to map the JSON.

I would advise you to create a class anyways. But, if you want to avoid it, you could use a `Map<String, String>`, as shown below:

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/jouer")
public void plays(@RequestBody Map<String, String> payload) {
    String name = payload.get("name");
}
```

---

If you go for the class approach, you would have something like:

```java
@Data
public class GuessAttempt {
    private String name;
}
```

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/jouer")
public void plays(@RequestBody GuessAttempt payload) {
    String name = payload.getName();
}
```

The [`@Data`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data) annotation is from [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/): It generates *all* the boilerplate code that is normally associated with simple beans:

- Getters for all fields;
- Setters for all non-final fields;
- Appropriate `toString()`, `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods;
- Constructor that initializes all final fields.

If you don't use Lombok, simply implement those methods manually.